# Binding doesn't work consistently in XAML

Tags: xaml, binding

For a Border within a Template specified under a Style:

```
<Thickness x:Key="CommonBorderThickness">2</Thickness>
<Style x:Key="CommonButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
...
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
...
   <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
...
                         <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
```

this works fine:

```
BorderThickness="{Binding Source={StaticResource CommonBorderThickness}, Converter={StaticResource FourGroupSizeConverter}}"
```

but these do not:

```
BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource FourGroupSizeConverter}}"
BorderThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource FourGroupSizeConverter}}"
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: What's the point of that converter you have on there? Also, on your setter for the template (where your TemplateBinding is looking) just set `Value="{StaticResource CommonBorderThickness}"` if you're actually trying to re-use that as the same property on multiple objects.

Comment: CommonBorderThickness is only used with the first BorderThickness assignment and is removed when the second or third assignments replace the first...  these two then use the Setter value instead... I included them all in the code sample for completeness, but only one would be used.  The Converter adapts the border thickness depending upon the window size and is also used with other BorderThickness as well as Margins and CornerRadius values throughout the App.